# Running hive query through the script by using crontab

Tags: shell, hive, cron

Hi I am executing the hive query through the shell script its executed perfectly at the same i am scheduling same script through the crontab it shows the one error. my script is as fallows

export JAVA_HOME=/install/bi/jdk
hiveQuery=`/install/bi/hive/bin/hive -e "
set hive.security.authorization.enabled=false;
select * from default.xmlsample;"`

echo $hiveQuery

And error is

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/install/bi/hive/lib/hive-common-0.12.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 2:14 Table not found 'xmlsample'
Any one can knows about this please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Table not found" error message suggests that when you run through cron, the Hive metastore is not being found. The metastore is the database which contains the metadata which maps table definitions to data in HDFS. It is often a separate RDBMS process such as MySQL or PostgreSQL. The details of the meta store are usually kept in the "hive-site.xml" file.

It seems that your cron process is not finding the same metastore as when you run the script yourself. It may be that an environment variable such as $HADOOP_HOME or $HIVE_HOME is not being set within the context where the cron job runs.